# How to encapsulate a property in a base class?

Tags: c#, oop, uml, object-oriented-analysis

My scenario is about developing Math Problems. As a `IProblem` interface, I thought that the two main properties that it should contain are `QuestionText` and `Response`. `QuestionText` always will be a string, but `Response` sometimes can be a complex object (a custom `Fraction` struc) or another datatype like string, decimal, int, etc.

```
    public interface IProblem
    {
        string QuestionText { get; set; }
        object Response { get; }

        bool IsComplete();
        bool IsCorrect();
    }
```

As you can see, `Response` is object. I guessed this datatype because all problems by nature have a response. And as it's an object, I define only get for future errors (casting problems).

My idea is later, in a concrete class to access to this property (`Response`), without the necessity to cast. Check it out?

```
    public abstract class Problem : IProblem
    {
        public string QuestionText { get; set;}
        public object Response { get; protected set; } 
        public virtual bool IsComplete()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public abstract bool IsCorrect();
    }

    public class BinaryProblem : Problem
    {
        public decimal N1 { get; set; }
        public decimal N2 { get; set; }
        public decimal Response
        {
            get { return (decimal)base.Response; }
            set { base.Response = value; }
        }

        public override bool IsCorrect()
        {
            return N1 + N2 == Response;
        }
    }
```

And here I'm testing the value.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BinaryProblem p = new BinaryProblem();
        p.N1 = 2;
        p.N2 = 4;

        p.Response = 6;

        IProblem p2 = p;
        Console.WriteLine(p2.Response);
        Console.WriteLine(p2.IsComplete().ToString());
    }
```

Until now, it works, but I want to know if what I'm doing is correct or a good practice. I've seen another people use `new` operator to do this. Others don't use the word `base`.

Is this a good way? Can it be causing future errors? Please, give me a feedback about my design.

EDIT: It's really necessary to access to the Response in a non-generic interface.

Comment: Personally, I would use either Generics or an IResponse interface over object.  By using object, a Response could literally be anything including A StringBuilder, and Int32 or even a WebRequest.  By using an interface or Generics you're going to have much tigher control over how Responses are implemented.

Comment: Yep, and; is `Reponse` always a numerical value?  If it is then just use the most accommodating numerical type, i.e., `double` or `decimal`, whichever is appropriate.

Comment: Agree with @ctorx, Generics would solve the problem much cleaner, while I like to hide class methods/properties in this case you would have to have a diff name for each type of result  and only show the result you want for the type of interface

Comment: Yes, in fact at the beginning I was thinking in that idea. I did this, because in my scenario I'm planning to create hundreds of this concrete classes using librarys (modules). And I guess that will be a problem.

Comment: Ok, you've convinced me! :) I guess I'm gonna use interfaces. So, the idea is to create each Response class for each datatype, right?

Comment: Well, I will use the most datatypes as answers: string, int, float, decimal, double, char, some enums, some custom complex objects (structs like Fraction).

Comment: this should move to chat ....

Comment: just one doubt (I don't want to extend the comment anymore), can someone show me your post with the idea of create these interfaces and set it to the concrete class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this? Note, I left some things out because they weren't important to the generic solution part of the problem (like QuestionText). I also left out the base class because it appeared to be nothing more than a pass-through, and an extra, unnecessary layer. This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but I hope it helps get you there.

First, this is how everything is used:
**Edit: Notice how they can all be treated as the non-generic IProblem now.**

```
private static void StackOverflowQuestion()
{
    IProblem<int> problem1 = new IntProblem(2, 4);
    problem1.Response = 6;

    IProblem<decimal> problem2 = new DecimalProblem(5, 10);
    problem2.Response = .5M;

    Console.WriteLine("Problem 1 is correct: {0}", problem1.IsCorrect());
    Console.WriteLine("Problem 2 is correct: {0}", problem2.IsCorrect());

    List<IProblem> problems = new List<IProblem>();
    problems.Add(problem1);
    problems.Add(problem2);
    problems.ForEach(problem => Debug.WriteLine(problem.GetResponse()));
}
```

**Edit: Here's the non-generic interface so many problems can be used in a list and treated the same way:**

```
public interface IProblem
{
    object GetResponse();
}
```

Here's the interface:
**Edit: Notice that this now implements the non-generic interface.**

```
public interface IProblem<T> : IProblem
{
    T Response { get; set; }
    bool IsCorrect();
}
```

And here are the classes:
**Edit: Notice the new GetResponse() methods.**

```
public class IntProblem : IProblem<int>
{
    private int _number1 { get; set; }
    private int _number2 { get; set; }

    public int Response { get; set; }

    public IntProblem(int number1, int number2)
    {
        this._number1 = number1;
        this._number2 = number2;
    }

    public bool IsCorrect()
    {
        return this._number1 + this._number2 == Response;
    }

    public object GetResponse()
    {
        return this.Response;
    }
}

public class DecimalProblem : IProblem<decimal>
{
    private decimal _number1 { get; set; }
    private decimal _number2 { get; set; }

    public decimal Response { get; set; }

    public DecimalProblem(decimal number1, decimal number2)
    {
        this._number1 = number1;
        this._number2 = number2;
    }

    public bool IsCorrect()
    {
        return this._number1 / this._number2 == Response;
    }

    public object GetResponse()
    {
        return this.Response;
    }
}
```

Comment: one problem bob, I need really necessary to access to the response in a non generic interface.. do you think that would be a big problem?

Comment: Well, if the response will be various types, then you'll need to treat it as an object, like in your example. Why do you need a non-generic interface?

Comment: because I'm planning to have a List<IProblem> and save into an XMLFile the responses. I was thinking doing something like using a foreach and saving the values into the file.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm looking for.. a non generic interface approach. thanks man!